# UNION query in DB2

Tags: db2, union

My query is:

```
SELECT BRAND,BRAND_GROUP, SUB_BRAND ,SUM(INCOME) AS TOTAL_INCOME FROM
"tema".MMT WHERE BRAND_GROUP IS NULL AND SUB_BRAND IS NULL GROUP BY
BRAND,BRAND_GROUP,SUB_BRAND

UNION
SELECT BRAND,BRAND_GROUP, SUB_BRAND ,SUM(INCOME) AS TOTAL_INCOME FROM
"tema".BGT WHERE BRAND_GROUP IS NULL AND SUB_BRAND IS NULL GROUP BY 
BRAND,BRAND_GROUP,SUB_BRAND;
```

and my output is :

```
BRAND BRAND_GROUP SUB_BRAND TOTAL_INCOME 
----- ----------- --------- ------------ 
GBS   NULL        NULL             10000
SWG   NULL        NULL             10000
GBS   NULL        NULL             20000
STG   NULL        NULL             20000
GTS   NULL        NULL             30000
```

The problem is that i have 2 categories of BRAND and I want to have just 1. Like this :

```
Brand       Brand_Group     Sub_brand       Total_Income
GBS                  -          -           30000
STG                  -          -           20000
GTS                  -          -           30000
SWG                  -          -           10000
```

Can someone help me with an ideea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to push your `UNION` query down into a sub-query, and then do the sum on the results of that, like below.

```
SELECT 
     BRAND
    ,BRAND_GROUP
    ,SUB_BRAND
    ,SUM(INCOME) AS TOTAL_INCOME
FROM (
    SELECT 
         BRAND
        ,BRAND_GROUP
        ,SUB_BRAND
        ,INCOME
    FROM "tema".MMT
    WHERE BRAND_GROUP IS NULL
      AND SUB_BRAND   IS NULL
    GROUP BY
         BRAND
        ,BRAND_GROUP
        ,SUB_BRAND

        UNION ALL

    SELECT
         BRAND
        ,BRAND_GROUP
        ,SUB_BRAND
        ,INCOME
    FROM "tema".BGT
    WHERE BRAND_GROUP IS NULL
      AND SUB_BRAND   IS NULL 
    GROUP BY 
         BRAND
        ,BRAND_GROUP
        ,SUB_BRAND
) tbl
GROUP BY 
     BRAND
    ,BRAND_GROUP
    ,SUB_BRAND
```

Two comments:

- I changed your query to use `UNION ALL` vs `UNION`, because `UNION` will eliminate duplicates.
- Do you need to select the `BRAND_GROUP` and `SUB_BRAND`, if you are only getting the rows that are null for those columns? Seems somewhat redundant to me.